# How to fix undefined reference LLVM error while linking CXX executable

Tags: makefile, cmake, clang, llvm

I was trying to build a llvm-slicer from:

https://github.com/IAIK/ios-analysis-llvmslicer

and I follow the instructions:

```sh
cd llvm-slicer
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AArch64;X86" -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=YES -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON ..
make -j4 opt
make -j4 llvm-slicer
```

But when I execute the last command `make -j4 llvm-slicer`, I got an error:

```sh
[100%] Built target LLVMAnalysis
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/llvm-slicer
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libLLVMSlicer.a(FunctionStaticSlicer.cpp.o): in function `llvm::Pass* llvm::callDefaultCtor<(anonymous namespace)::FunctionSlicer>()':
FunctionStaticSlicer.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm15callDefaultCtorIN12_GLOBAL__N_114FunctionSlicerEEEPNS_4PassEv+0x1c): undefined reference to `vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FunctionSlicer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [tools/llvm-slicer/CMakeFiles/llvm-slicer.dir/build.make:116: bin/llvm-slicer] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9647: tools/llvm-slicer/CMakeFiles/llvm-slicer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9654: tools/llvm-slicer/CMakeFiles/llvm-slicer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:2740: llvm-slicer] Error 2
```

I have no idea about how to fix it and I couldn't find any similar issues on Google, I hope someone can help me to figure it out, many thx.

Comment: Maybe a parallelism issue? Drop the `-j4` options and start from scratch to test this hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several scenarios for this issue, but in my opinion, here the scenario is for the given information that your default compiler (`_ZN...something` errors mostly because of compilers or linkers) is earlier version of gnu (gcc for c, g++ for c++) in your host pc (or maybe another compiler other than clang) and struggling about resolving a c++ feature `anonymous namespace`, as, a part of given error says:

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libLLVMSlicer.a(FunctionStaticSlicer.cpp.o): in function `llvm::Pass* llvm::callDefaultCtor<(anonymous namespace)::FunctionSlicer>()':
FunctionStaticSlicer.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm15callDefaultCtorIN12_GLOBAL__N_114FunctionSlicerEEEPNS_4PassEv+0x1c): undefined reference to `vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FunctionSlicer'
```

For this, there are several things you can do:

**1-)** You can change your compiler for building. In command window, you can export `clang` and `clang++` as your compiler **before cmake configuration**. Here I assume that you installed new versions of clang compiler from anywhere, even github clone, I can give several examples here how to export and you can adapt one of them to your case easily:

```sh
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
```

another version:

```sh
export CC=clang-11
export CXX=clang++-11
```

another version:

```sh
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

another version:

```sh
export CC=/usr/bin/clang-12
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++-12
```

another github clone version:

```sh
export CC=~/llvm/llvm-project/build/bin/clang
export CXX=~/llvm/llvm-project/build/bin/clang++
```

Even if this does not change your compiler, you can change your compiler while configuring with cmake by `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER={your-c-compiler}` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER={your-c++-compiler}` cmake flags. Try either with `gcc` or `clang`. Here is an example configuration in your case:

```sh
cmake \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AArch64;X86" \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=YES \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON ..
```

**2-)**  Error can be because of c++ standard, you can add `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14` (Default C++ standard using by LLVM) flag as cmake configuration like:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AArch64;X86" -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=YES -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14 ..`

**3-)** Even if didn't work above cases, you can remove anonymous namespace from `FunctionStaticSlicer.cpp` file (given in the error message) and try to build again. You can find these lines like this:

```cpp
// some code here and do not delete

namespace { // delete this line 
// as you can see there is no name of namespace that's why called 'anonymous'
// if it was it would be like 'namespace nmspcName {'

// some code here and do not delete

} // and delete this line, too

// some code here and do not delete
```

But this is **really bad practice**, even if it can solve your problem, I do not recommend.

Also you can try to do similar changes in `CMakeLists.txt` file or adding other cmake configuration flags, however in my opinion, you could solve your problem easily by 1. option which is changing your default compiler.